# Multiple java applications on VPS causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, memory, vps

Memory when I run one application (Minecraft Server)

```
free -m
              Gesamt   belegt    frei        gemns. Puffer/Cache verfügbar
Speicher:        8192        1934        6103           1         154        6252

Auslagerungsspeicher:           0           0           0
```

ulimit

```
ulimit -s
8192
```

ulimit all

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1546762
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Java version

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I try to start a additional Java Application

```
java -jar bot.jar
[0,063s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.start(CleanerImpl.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.ref.Cleaner.create(Cleaner.java:203)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.ref.CleanerFactory.<clinit>(CleanerFactory.java:42)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:724)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:346)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:317)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:256)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(LauncherHelper.java:521)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:747)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:655)
```

I tried so much, I really don't know what to do anymore. Last time I tried to fix that, I had to reinstall my whole Server because I'm new with all that linux stuff

Comment: Well yea.  The virtual server has a limited amount of memory.  If your Java apps ask the operating system for too much memory, it will refuse and you will get this kind of OOM exception.  Solutions: 1) run fewer Java apps, 2) make them smaller, 3) pay more money for a VPS with more memory.

Comment: Note that this particular failure is happening thread creation.  The JVM is requesting memory for a thread stack ... outside of the Java heap.  It *could be* that the problem is that your application has too many threads ... or is using too much off-heap memory in general.  Or maybe you just made the heap too big and the JVM has reserved all of the available RAM for that.

Comment: Finally, it could actually be swap space that is the problem, but on a VPS you probably want to avoid using swap ... because performance will be terrible.

Comment: Well both applications run with no problem, when they run alone and they don't have such an error. And that the application uses to much memory, I limited the MC-Server to user max 4GB and the other should run with only 2GB but if one of the applications run, the other isn't able to start.

Comment: *"I limited the MC-Server to user max 4GB"* - How?  *"The other should run with only 2GB"* - How do you know?   Remember that a JVM uses memory that is not Heap memory.  In some cases ... quite a lot.

Comment: I limited the minecraft server by typing -Xmx4G as argument, I don't know if that really do what it should, but if I need more RAM to run an additional application, then I came to a conclusion

Comment: OK.  So -Xmx4G is only limiting the main heap size.  If you want  to limit all memory usage for the process, use ulimit.

Comment: Should I use ulimit in the console or as a Java argument?

Comment: It is not a JVM option.  It should be run in the shell from which the command is being launched.